# OCaml produce shared object with OCaml runtime linked in

Tags: python, ocaml

I'm trying to build a shared object out of an OCaml library that I can run under `Python` using the `cdll` interface in `ctypes`.

Is there a way to direct something in the OCaml toolchain to produce a shared object with its dependencies linked in?

I'm starting to suspect that OCaml simply does not support what I'm trying to do. I want to call an OCaml function, but then have it produce some kind of result and return control back to where it was called from.

Here's my OCaml library

```
(* foo.ml *)
let add x y = x + y
```

And the command I used to compile it on OS X. (using `.so` instead of `.dylib` is slightly violating the naming conventions of the platform, but `ocamlopt` will only accept an extension of `.o` or `.so`.)

```
$ ocamlopt -output-obj -fPIC -o foo.so foo.ml
```

succeeds and produces `foo.so`.

Here's my first attempt to load the shared object into a python program (python 3.6).

```
# foo.py
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')

print("Loaded")
```

It produces the following error when run

excerpt:

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(./foo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _caml_code_area_end
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(./foo.so, 6): Symbol not found: _caml_code_area_end
  Referenced from: ./foo.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in ./foo.so
```

I looked around for the symbol in the compiler's directory `ocamlopt -where`.

```
$ find `ocamlopt -where` | xargs -I% bash -c 'nm % | sed -e "s|^|%:|"' | & grep _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_pic.a: 0000000000000008 C _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_pic.a:                  U _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrunp.a: 0000000000000008 C _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrunp.a:                  U _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so: 000000000001ded0 S _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a: 0000000000000008 C _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun.a:                  U _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrund.a: 0000000000000008 C _caml_code_area_end
/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrund.a:                  U _caml_code_area_end
```

And tried loading `/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so` first, giving

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so')
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./foo.so')

print("Loaded")
```

which produced the error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so, 6): Symbol not found: _caml_apply2
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/ocaml/libasmrun_shared.so
```

The `_caml_apply2` symbol is deep in the runtime of OCaml, and I wasn't able to find a file for it with the `.so` extension ... and `cdll` doesn't seem to expose the ability to load `.a`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, the `-fPIC` flag is not enough, you also need a PIC runtime. Previously, this required a special switch (such as `4.04.1+fPIC`), but now you can select which runtime to link against.

The following works for me (Debian buster, opam 4.06.1+rc2 switch):

```
% ocamlopt -output-obj -runtime-variant _pic -o foo.so foo.ml
% python foo.py
Loaded
```

> I'm trying to build a shared object out of an OCaml library that I can run under Python using the cdll interface in ctypes.

Note that you won't be able to just call the OCaml symbols from Python (or another interface), you'll need to write some C that sets up the runtime and manages the OCaml objects. A simple way to do that is to use [Cstubs_inverted](http://ocamllabs.io/ocaml-ctypes/Cstubs_inverted.html) for this part.